# strings and pointers manipulation

Tags: c, string

I am trying to print all the 4 strings in the given program. But I am unable to print the strings. With the code below I get some weird output.

```
int main()
{
    char szStr[] = "India\0Japan\0America\0Australia";
    char *p = szStr;

    while(p)
    {
        printf("%c", p);
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which kind of weird output? Try also ending "Australia" with the string terminator "\0"

Comment: Why are you complicating your life?

Comment: Your loop will never end.

Comment: @Vik What? In a string literal, that's included automatically!

Comment: Do you need to have them all in one string literal like that? The normal approach would be to use an array of strings like `char * szStr[] = {"India", "Japan", "America", "Australia"};`. Then use `%s` in the `printf`, not `%c`. And you'll need a different way of knowing when to stop.

Comment: @Matthew: sure it will, when it hits the null term at the end of "India".

Comment: @Matthew: never mind, I get it now. It would need to be `while(*p)`.

Comment: I'm soo rusty with C :)

Comment: This is not the way strings are suppose to be implemented in C. I hope(almost sure) this is just for practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tested and works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char szStr[] = "India\0Japan\0America\0Australia\0";
    char *p = szStr;

    while(*p)
    {
        p += printf("%s", p);
        p++;
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the extra null-terminator on the string. This is actually important, despite the fact that the string literal has it's own null-term. The double null-term is necessary to terminate the while loop correctly.

### Explanation:

`printf` returns the number of characters written, i.e., the length of each string, not including the null terminator. So when you add this to `p`, you're left with `p` pointing at the null-terminator. Increment `p` again and you're at the start of the next string. If that string is length-0, then `p` is once again pointing to a null-terminator, so the while loop will bail. That's why you need the extra null-terminator on the end of the string.

Comment: Clever, but for extra safety and readability, I'd separate the `p += printf("%s", p);` statement in two statements. You know, it's not obvious where/if there are sequence points, and we better avoid UB.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted explain why so I can improve it? thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3: Not sure what you mean by sequence points or UB. Could you explain? Modify-assigment operators (like `+=`) are always contentious: some people think they're too cryptic or subtle, but I prefer them over introducing variables that are only used once. Just a matter of coding style.

Comment: I happen to be one of the people you are talking about. It's not that I don't understand what the code does, I just don't want to have to think about it fore more than a quarter of a second.

Comment: @sh1fts0rm - It's not the `+=` operator I'm concerned with. It's the way you used it. `p += printf("%s", p)` *can* falsely suggest that p is being modified *while* printed. But don't take me wrong, I'm not saying that your code is wrong by any means... I just noticed this subtlety.

Comment: Oh, I got you. Yes, that's a possible source of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(p)
```

is the same as

```
while(p != NULL)
```

which is of course always true - the string literal points to a valid memory location. I feel you are confusing this with

```
while(*p)
```

or with the equivalent

```
while(*p != 0)
```

because that would run until it finds the 0-terminator in the string. **That's not good enough either, though.** You don't know **which** string you just printed. You have to keep track of the number of strings manually. Also, why print it character-by-character, invoking the quite expensive `printf()` function for every byte you display? It's just wasteful. How about something like

```
char szStr[] = "India\0Japan\0America\0Australia";

char *p = szStr;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    puts(p);
    p += strlen(p) + 1;
}
```

**Still, I don't see why this is simpler or otherwise better than simply storing an array of strings.** Like this:

```
const char *strings[] = {
    "India",
    "Japan",
    "America",
    "Australia"
};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]); i++)
    puts(strings[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`%c` is format specifier for printing a single character. Use `%s` instead. Still printf will only print the string up to the first `\0` character. You will have to perform some kind of split before printing if you want the four strings to be output. Maybe use `sscanf` with `"%s%s%s%s"`.

Comment: True but not sufficient for what the OP wants. The will just print each suffix of the first string "India."

Comment: Eh, it's still not much of an answer. More of a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `while(p)` to `while(*p)`.

In `c`, anything other than 0 will be considered true and 0 will be considered false.

So, `p` is not 0 and it makes the `while` loop repeat ever and ever again.

But `*p` will become 0 at the end of the string.

Comment: That will only print every suffix of the first string "India". The OP wants to print each string embedded in the character array.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `*p` gets you the value pointed by `p`.

This will work:

```
int main()
{
    char szStr[] = "India\0Japan\0America\0Australia\0";
    char *p = szStr;
    int numOfStrings = 4;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; i++)
    {
        while(*p)
        {
            printf("%c", *p);
            p++;
        }
        printf(" "); //print a space character to separate your strings
        p++; //advance pointer to skip '\0' between strings
    }    
    return 0;
}
```